# Testing types for release of software in short span of time

Tags: manual-testing, release

My question is

> What testing types can be used to release the product or project in short span of time.

Ex: I got requirement today that need to be deliver by tomorrow, Here what testing type I need to use.

Please revert back your feedback ASAP

Answer (score 2):

> What testing types can be used to release the product or project in short span of time.

- Exploratory testing, you use your common sense to look for bugs.
- Regression testing, does this new feature break anything that has been working?
- Crowd testing (not really an official testing technique), you get a few more people to execute exploratory testing using brain storming.

Comment: Yu Zhang thanks for your information. Assume that here my requirement is new for the new project. In this case how regression will work. Please correct me if anything am wrong

Comment: @Anand, even a requirement is new to this project, regression tests are still applicable. Say, you add a new function to your mobile app, you still need to apply regression tests to make sure older functions are still working.

Answer (score 1):

I think same tests as for a long span of time, maybe just less of them covering less paths and options.

So I still say think about the 4 quadrants of Agile testing and choose which Unit, Integrated, User Acceptance and Exploratory tests to do

Still think about the pyramid of testing with (few) manual exploratory tests on top and (many) unit tests on the bottom

Out of happy, sad and optional paths, start with the happy one that actually works for your users, earns your company revenue, etc.

If I had to choose just one form of testing?  I would choose end-to-end testing from a user acceptance level using selenium based code for automation.  However given the time frame of a day or two all you could expect to achieve would be manual testing.  If this is basically fairly standard practice you should also make some effort with your company and management to test things properly.  One day for manual testing and no automation will limit both your growth and that of the company concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Conducting a "bug hunt" or "test jam" is usually a good way to get a lot of testing, and a lot of communication about quality, happening quickly.

Conducting a bug hunt means pulling together many people from the organization, developers, PM, marketing, support, managers/executives, and have everyone test the product together.  I usually do these for 2 hours, and often include lunch.

I'll often give prizes in categories like "most interesting bug" or "most bugs found" or "highest severity bug found".

You can setup roles/personas ahead of time, and ask people to focus on different areas.

This is a form of crowd-source testing, where the crowd are the folks in your company.  A side benefit, everyone in the bug hunt (PM, managers, etc.) will experience first hand the quality of the software - lending credibility to your test report.